# This GUI is displaying nothing after setting BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, boxlayout

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI_Borrower extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
    JLabel lblProg = new JLabel("Program:");
    JLabel lblId = new JLabel("Library ID: ");
    JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Add Borrower");
    JTextField txtName = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField txtProg = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField txtId = new JTextField(10);
    static int counter = 19000;
    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");

    public GUI_Borrower() {
        super("Add Borrower");
        makeFrame();
        showFrame();
    }

    public void makeFrame() {
        lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Forte", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        lblTitle.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        add(lblTitle);
        add(lblName);
        add(txtName);
        add(lblProg);
        add(txtProg);
        add(lblId);
        add(txtId);

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.add(btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void showFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object source = ae.getSource();

        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Confirm")) {
            txtName.setText("");
            txtProg.setText("");
            btnSubmit.setText("Submit");
        } else if (source == btnSubmit) {
            if (txtName.getText().equals("") && txtProg.getText().equals("")) {
                txtId.setText("No entry of both");
            } else if (txtName.getText().equals("")) {
                txtId.setText("No entry of Name");
            } else if (txtProg.getText().equals("")) {
                txtId.setText("No entry of Program");
            } else {
                counter++;
                txtId.setText("" + counter);

                btnSubmit.setText("Confirm");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI_Borrower();
    }
}
```

I tried adding `BoxLayout` because all the text fields and labels are on one line. So I tried box Layout and failed.

Can anyone show me how to make it like the title one line, label Different line, button different line?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: in makeFrame() or showFrame()?

Comment: The default layout manager for a frame is a `BorderLayout`. When you add the component to the frame without a constraint the component will go to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` constraint which can only display a single component, so only the last component added will be visible. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). you can download the working demos and then make changes. I would suggest you can use the `GridBagLayout` to achieve your desired layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As camickr says in his comment, you generally use a `GridBagLayout` to create a form.

I reworked your code because I hope to show a better way to code a GUI panel.

Here's the GUI.

[image: Add Borrower GUI]

The major changes I made include:

1. All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that all Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. I organized the GUI code into three methods so I could focus on one part of the GUI at a time.  The `JFrame` is created in the `run` method.  The title `JPanel` is created in the `createTitlePanel` method.  The form `JPanel` is created in the `createFormPanel` method. The code for the `JFrame` will rarely change from Swing application to Swing application.
3. I use Swing components.  I don't extend Swing components, or any Java class, unless I intend to override one of the class methods.
4. The `createFormPanel` class uses the `GridBagLayout` to organize the labels and text fields in columns.  You can think of the `GridBagLayout` as a flexible grid.  The cells of the grid don't have to be the same size.  The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), has another example.
5. I put the `ActionListener` in a separate class.  I made it an inner class in this example so I could paste the code as one file.  Generally, you should put separate classes in separate files.  It makes each class shorter and easier to understand.

Here's the runnable, example code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BorrowerGUI implements Runnable {

    private static int ID_COUNTER = 19000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BorrowerGUI());
    }

    private JButton btnSubmit;

    private JTextField txtName;
    private JTextField txtProg;
    private JTextField txtId;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add Borrower");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createTitlePanel(), BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        frame.add(createFormPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTitlePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Add Borrower");
        lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Forte", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        lblTitle.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        panel.add(lblTitle);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createFormPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
        panel.add(lblName, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        txtName = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(txtName, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel lblProg = new JLabel("Program:");
        panel.add(lblProg, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        txtProg = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(txtProg, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel lblId = new JLabel("Library ID:");
        panel.add(lblId, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        txtId = new JTextField(20);
        txtId.setEditable(false);
        panel.add(txtId, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new SubmitListener());
        panel.add(btnSubmit, gbc);

        return panel;
    }

    public class SubmitListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            Object source = ae.getSource();

            if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Confirm")) {
                txtName.setText("");
                txtName.requestFocus();
                txtProg.setText("");
                txtId.setText("");
                btnSubmit.setText("Submit");
            } else if (source == btnSubmit) {
                if (txtName.getText().equals("") &&
                        txtProg.getText().equals("")) {
                    txtId.setText("No entry of both");
                } else if (txtName.getText().equals("")) {
                    txtId.setText("No entry of Name");
                } else if (txtProg.getText().equals("")) {
                    txtId.setText("No entry of Program");
                } else {
                    ID_COUNTER++;
                    txtId.setText("" + ID_COUNTER);
                    btnSubmit.setText("Confirm");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Edited to add:  If you want the title `JLabel` to be right-justified, you'll have to switch to a `BorderLayout`.  I added an empty border so the text wouldn't be on the right edge of the `JFrame`.

Here's the changed method.

```
private JPanel createTitlePanel(String title) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 10));

    JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel(title);
    lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Forte", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    lblTitle.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    panel.add(lblTitle, BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);

    return panel;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gilbert, i will go to through the code and ask if i dont understand anything. i appreciate your help because you made my work easier.

Comment: how to do allignment changes in this layout? like (FlowLayout.RIGHT)?

Comment: @Arvind Varma: Which alignment change?  The title panel layout is centered.  You can change the background color of the JPanels to see their size and orientation.

Comment: the name,program,id aligned to right like the pic above i posted