# centering a button in 2 grids using GridBagLayout (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I am curious if it possible to center a JButton in two X grids of a GridBagLayout? I've done some searching through the API but haven't found much. I have also drawn up a small picture to clarify what I am trying to do.

Thank you!

Example Image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTzMQ.png]

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63638937/this-gui-is-displaying-nothing-after-setting-boxlayout/63639803#63639803) from one of my recent answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've done some searching through the API but haven't found much.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

You would need to concentrate on the `Specifying Constraints` section:

1. the `gridwidth` constraint will allow the button to span multiple columns
2. the `anchor` constraint will allow the button to be centered within the two columns.
3. the `fill` constraint will need to be turned off.

The above assumes that you actually have other components on the panel in each of the columns. You can't just randomly say a single component takes up two columns.

So start with the demo code in the tutorial an modify it to have the button on the bottom centered.